# can public static final string variables be overridien in sub-classes?

Tags: java

Here is the sample program:

```
public class Base {
    public static final String FOO = "foo";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base b = new Base();
        Sub s = new Sub();
        System.out.print(Base.FOO);
        System.out.print(Sub.FOO);
        System.out.print(b.FOO);
        System.out.print(s.FOO);
        System.out.print(((Base)s).FOO);
    }
}
class Sub extends Base {
    public static final String FOO="bar";
}
```

When I execute this it's printing `foobarfoobarfoo`.

Since String `FOO` is declared as `public static final`, my understanding is its value cannot be changed anymore. But in the subclass `Sub`, the value is being changed to `bar`.

Shouldn't the program throw a compilation error?
Why is it printing `foobarfoobarfoo`?

Comment: Fields are not overridden. `static` members are not overridden either.

Answer (score 3):

Static variables are not inherited, they belong to the class, that's why they are *static*. The subclasses can have static fields with the same, though.

Comment: Thank you , got it,. But since it was having final keyword also i was confused